# How to change default port in MarkLogic9(Linux Red Hat)

Tags: linux, redhat

Installed MarkLogic in Red hat environment with default port 8000 but i need to change the default port. 
Gone through Marklogic documnets without luck.
Some one let me know the procedure to change the default port.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to find out. Go to Marklogic installation directory /MarkLogic_Home/config/groups.xml
Under this find for default port and change accordingly.